# When do events of Spider-man: Far From Home happen?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

I don't quite understand where in MCU events of *Spider-man: Far From Home* take place. Are they before *Avengers: Infinity War* or after *Avengers: Endgame*?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203481/is-spider-man-far-from-home-set-before-or-after-avengers-endgame

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in June 2017, Sony producer Amy Pascal revealed in [a Fandom exclusive interview](https://www.fandom.com/articles/exclusive-sonys-spider-man-movies-happen-in-the-same-reality-as-the-mcu) it would take place "a few minutes after" the fourth *Avengers* movie.

> The duo have also been talking about where the Spider-Man sequel fits into the MCU timeline. The sequel will arrive in 2020, two months after *Avengers 4*. But, like *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, – which, to quote Feige picks up “right after Peter’s adventures in [Captain America:] *Civil War*” – the events of the Homecoming sequel will pick up immediately where the fourth *Avengers* film leaves off.
>
> “What I think we should focus on is this Spider-Man who started in *Civil War* and then has this movie, and then will be in the *Avengers* movie. And we are starting now the next one which will start a few minutes after *Avengers 4* wraps as a story,” Pascal reveals.

Admittedly, foreshadowing is what it is in the MCU, so as this interview was given a year ago, it could be subject to a "tweak" of sorts.